# Web video player

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video

Well I'm looking for a video player that I can embed in my web (sorry if I'm not using the appropriate terms, I didn't know what words to look up). I've tried many JS and CSS based like MediaElement or flarevideo, but with all of them I would need to provide every video in three formats (mp4, ogv and webm) for it to work in all browsers. I would like to know if there is any (if possible with HTML5 and fallback to flash) that can play a video in a given format (say mp4) in all browsers (or in most of them).

I think that the issue with the three formats is because I try to use HTML5 too, but it is not a real requirement. I hope this question is not repeated, I must say that I could not find proper words to look up, don't know if those terms are correct.

Comment: Not to worry, all of your terms are, in fact, pretty appropriate!

Comment: The 3 format thing is the case, if you want to support multiple (and also mobile) browsers, that is the deal for now.  There is no fix for that that I am aware of, unless you put the video on a 3rd party site, and have them handle the conversions.

Comment: @nycynik: there are lots of tools that allow you to take a video and easily convert it into several video formats. However, you still have the trouble of uploading them and pointing to them. It's a lot of work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real best bet is to use [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com) or [Vimeo](http://www.vimeo.com) and then simply embed the video into your website. You'll have no problems with compatibility, they run on HTML5 and fall back to Flash when necessary, work on mobile devices, and you won't run into storage problems on your host, either!

Comment: And sadly this really has to be considered a valid answer these days. Anymore as a web shop we strongly discourage the hosting and supporting of your own videos when these services exist and are free for the most part. You can use pro versions of both to increase your options, should you need full control of what happens when the video ends and so on.

Comment: I wouldn't think it'd be too sad, @KaiQing. Vimeo and YouTube are robust, powerful platforms: they provide more functionality and connectivity than the average developer would dare desire to work to implement on their own!

Comment: yeah but the dependencies of third party hosted solutions means the stability of your site is no longer entirely up to you. Plus, at any point policies or code may change and force you to update. This could be considered paranoia since so many sites, even this one, use things like foreign logins and such and typically the maintenance is minimal. I just don't like putting so much power in outside sources.

Comment: I think you are right, I will probably use the pro or the plus version of Vimeo. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jordan's answer above but there are times when you have to host yourself.

I recently completed a project for a client who did not want to deliver video using **progressive download** (for fear that the video content could easily be copied and used for free).  I tried to talk them into Vimeo and Youtube but the value of the service they provide is in the video content they deliver and they wanted to own **fully own and customize** the solution.

**The requirements** was to deliver video to the widest number of browsers and devices.  And I wanted to keep things simple so I wanted a single player that would work for all platforms.

The also wanted to deliver the video securely.

**The one fit solution I ended up with was:**

- Player: JW Player - Which has flash fallback
- Host: [Azure Media Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/16/azure-media-services-now-supported-by-jw-player/) Pay as you go service
- Video Format: HLS Version 3 (which is supported natively by the largest number of browsers and devices)

AWS Cloudfront would have also worked but it felt like Azure pricing was more aggressive.  I just wanted the cheapest video stream delivery solution (that scales) to prove things out and I ended up sticking with Azure.  It also felt like a more cohesive solution that AWS solutions.

But if you don't need to worry about providing an adaptive streaming solution, than you can more easily deliver video from S3 or the [Azure blob store](http://programmerpayback.com/2013/01/30/hosting-progressive-download-videos-on-azure-blobs/).

Other technologies to look in to for adaptive streaming: MPEG-DASH (it's the future imho, but support is still limited to the latest browsers and devices)

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at http://www.dash-player.com, which is a MPEG-DASH as well as HLS player for HTML5, and Flash as fallback.